# Calculating sine of radian in C

Tags: c, math.h, radians

Working on a simple school problem using C to calculate sine of 1 radian.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

     double radian = (180 / M_PI);
     double y = sin(radian);
     printf("The sine of 1 radian is %.3f", y);

     return 0;
}
```

The sine of a radian is 0.841, but I'm getting 0.680. Is this because of how I am calculating 1 radian, instead of just using `radians`?

Comment: `sin()` takes radians. To find the sine of 1 radian, just do `sin(1)`.

Comment: thanks @sneftel clearly I need to be remembering basic math

Comment: @azochz: Technically 1 radian is 180/pi (in degrees)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`180 / pi` is one radian IN DEGREES.
But the `sin()` function takes a value in radian.
So it's just `sin(1)`.